# Apex is replacing Javascript content from string

Tags: apex

I am assigning below string to a rich text field

```
myobj obj = new myobj();
obj.myrichtextfld = '<img src=r onclick=alert(document.cookie)>'; 
insert obj;
 myobj obj2 = [select myrichtextfld  from obj2 ];
 system.debug(obj2.myrichtextfld); // outputs <img src=""></img>
```

While inserting apex is replacing javascript contents. Any idea how to prevent this

Comment: Sounds to me like Salesforce is doing you a favor. You're essentially trying to XSS (cross-site scripting) yourself. This also sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem you're trying to solve, and you've come up with this self-XSS as a solution. Instead of asking how to make your solution work, you should try asking about how to solve the problem itself.

Comment: No i am just testing the code. Hopefully it can be achieved using escapeHtml4 and unescapeHtml4 funtion. Thanks

Comment: You're trying to deliberately introduce XSS vulnerabilities? You're missing quotes around the values, anyway...